# Why does this integral equals to given output?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

I was reading about Gaussian distribution function:

[image]

and I saw this formula:

[image]

I don't understand why that integral is equal to $$\frac{\phi (t)}{t}$$ It seems like it must be equal to infinity. And how does $$\phi (t)$$ function works there?

my question is to explain how last step in that formula works. why does that last integral is equal to $\frac{\phi (t)}{t}$

Comment: Note that you need $t>0$ for the inequality to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is how we can evaluate the integral
$$\int\limits_{t}^{\infty}x\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{x^2}{2} \right\}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{t}^{\infty}x\exp\left\{-\frac{x^2}{2} \right\}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$
Substitute $u=-x^2/2$. The differential is going to be $\mathrm{d}x=-x^{-1}\mathrm{d}u$. This will yield
$$-\frac{1}{{\sqrt{2\pi}}}\int\limits_{-t^2/2}^{\infty}e^u\,\mathrm{d}u = \frac{1}{{\sqrt{2\pi}}}\exp\left\{-\frac{t^2}{2} \right\}.$$
This is our desired $\phi(t)$.

Comment: my question is about why in formula in question $$P(X>t) = \frac{\phi (t)}{t}$$. Why that probability is equal to that output.

Comment: You said "I dont understand why this *integral* is equal to...".

Comment: yeah integral of $x \phi (x) dx$. which is before $\frac{\phi (t)}{t}$

Comment: cool. but my question is to explain how last step in that formula works. why does that last integral is equal to $\frac{\phi (t)}{t}$

Comment: But I did calculate it???

Comment: @french_fries If you read carefully the statement reads $$P (X>t)\le\frac\phi t.$$

Comment: @user right. but $\frac{\phi (t)}{t}$ is output of integral $x \phi (x) dx$. i don't understand that part.

Comment: @user Can you help us? Did I calculate the integral of $x\phi(x)$ or not?

Comment: @vitamind question is "Why does this integral equals to given output?". not calculate integral....

Comment: Quote: "I don't understand why that integral is equal to"

Comment: I will edit my question for you, but see what I calculuted originally. Just divide $t$ on both sides.

Comment: got it!) thanks

Comment: Glad you did. I added the $1/t$ on both sides either way now.